# How do I reload my listview from another windows form class?

Tags: c#, listview

So I'm working with a windows form application that brings information from a LAMP server and I need help because I don't know how to make this work as intended.

[image: Apologies for the portuguese GUI]

In this segment I can select a row from my listview, choose "Excluir" which calls a secondary windows form class with details about the selected row. When I press "Excluir" in this secondary form the displayed information is deleted from my database as intended and the form is closed, but my listview does not update. I tried to call for my listview method again but it just duplicates information instead of updating it. Follows my listview method:

```
public void carregarListaUsuarios()
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++)
        {
            urlLoader = "accounts/returnUserById.php";

            obj = new POSTobject();
            obj.POSTrequest("param1=" + listaID[i], urlLoader); //send request to database with row ID

            users[i] = parseUsers(obj, 7); //get the full row for each entry
            lvi = new ListViewItem(users[i].getId());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(users[i].getPNome());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(users[i].getSNome());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(users[i].getCargo());
            lvGerenciarUsers.Items.Add(lvi); //add to the listview row
        } //for
    }
```

Apologies for the portuguese GUI, hope I made my question clear enough.

Edit1: forgot to mention, this method used to load my listview is being called in the main form constructor class.

Comment: Well, you already know how to do this.  You have a Button class and a Form class, your Form class can see that something interesting happened with the button object.  You wrote a Click event handler.  Just do the exact same thing.  Raise an event in the 2nd form class, the 1st form class can subscribe it to refresh the listview.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't manage to figure out the right way to do it, but found an optional solution from another one of your posts about how to make an event handler to focus this tab page "Gerenciar usuários" whenever my secondary form closes so it ends up reloading accordingly. I know this is not the most optimal way to do it, but it works in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add lvGerenciarUsers.Items.Clear() just above for loop it will clean all the items and then for loop will add New Updated items again.

Comment: Oh wait now it works! I had to use lvGerenciarUsers.Items.Clear() though. Have tried before but didn't quite figured out I needed the ".Items." segment. Now I only have to find a way to reload my main form from my secondary window when the button is pressed.